# My animation is not returning to idle but goes from idle to run animation and then never returns

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I need help my animation is not returning back to idle this is for my enemy. I have the transitions set up in the animator and i have a bool parameter for true and false and no I don't want to use unity built in ai thing.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BossMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;
    public float distance;
    public Transform target;
    public float speed = 4f;
    Rigidbody rig;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        whento();
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void followPlayer()
    {
        Vector3 pos = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        rig.MovePosition(pos);
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
    void whento()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, distance))
        {

            if (hit.transform.tag == "Player")
            {
                followPlayer();
                anim.SetBool("isMoving", true);
            }

            else if (hit.transform.tag != "Player")
            {
                anim.SetBool("isMoving", false);
            }
        }
        

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note. Since the "target" variable appears to never change, and is getting called in Update, you don't to call it in followPlayer.

Comment: Hi, not sure if this is what is causing the problem, but from what I can see you are using RaycastHit... You are checking the tags of the things you hit. So what happens when you hit nothing?

I am not the best with Rays, but it seems like you could just place an else at the end of your if statement (the Raycast if statement). That way, if you hit nothing, it will run a different piece of code (idle animation, or even start searching for player).

Comment: wait thats why i put this so if it does not hit player then it plays a different animation, sorry im pretty new to this btw :

 else if( hit.transform.tag != "Player")
            {
                anim.SetBool("IsMoving", false);
            }

Comment: Have you tried Pontako's suggestion. It basically what I was saying, but easier (and more efficient). Change the else if to an else, and it will catch everything that is not tagged Player and also work if your ray hits nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the last `else if` Statement to just an `else` Statement. This way your code works regardless if you hit something or not.